# linux spring tool suite (eclipse) launches from terminal but not from desktop

Tags: java, linux, spring-tool-suite, linux-mint

I am setting up Spring Tool Suite IDE on a linux mint cinnamon machine.

I have installed the JDK, added it to my path. When I do java -version everything works. When I navigate to the folder containing Spring tool suite and execute it using

`./STS` it launches correctly.

When I navigate to that file in finder, and click on it, I get the java error about no JDK installed.

Any ideas ?

**Edit:** Spring Tool suite is basically a version of eclipse if you haven't heard of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert into the 1st line of your `STS.ini` the following

```
-vm
path/to/your/jdk/bin/java
```

replacing `path/to/your/jdk` with actual path.

`STS.ini` is near `STS` executable file (within the same folder).